# Update apk build by flutter on play store on other build apk that was build by android previously

Tags: android, flutter, google-play

I have an app on play store i have made that on android. Now i have to make that on flutter. Will apk build on flutter with same package name can be updated on play store for same id.

I have no idea about this scenerio

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, you application will have the same id on PlayStore**

The application id is only affected if you change the `applicationId` in the project's module `build.gradle` file. The file found here `project/module/build.gradle`.

When you start using Flutter, this file is located here `project/android/module/build.gradle` eg. Let's say that the project folder is `FunnyJokes` and you used Android Studio to create your project. Then the location is `FunnyJokes/app/build.gradle` where `app` is the name of the module. When you use flutter, this **might** change to `FunnyJokes/android/app/build.gradle`

I hope this answers your question extensively.

**NB:** Also make sure you never lose/change your keystore. If this happens, then you **might** never be able to update the app on Play Store with the same package name or `applicationId`